# Grep regular expression - Pattern issue

Tags: grep

I'm trying to using grep to try to find things from a given pattern. For instance I have these lines:

```
A secret word: CoolKapplan
A secret word: Kapplan
A secret word: Bungyjump
```

So if I get to know the first and last letter of a word. In this example I get 'K' - 'n'.

```
PATTERN = K.....n
I do this: grep -w -r -H --color=always "^$PATTERN" *
```

And I except it to only give me the lines containing the patterns that are starting with K. But that command would also include the first line, so the result would be:

```
A secret word: CoolKapplan
A secret word: Kapplan
```

How do I make it so it searches for a pattern and not give me the pattern that is included in another word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trial and error attempts I found out that you have to add '-o' flag for it to work.